# Issue with transform ldapsearch command to flask_ldap3_login settings

Tags: python, flask, active-directory, ldap

I have a problem with transform **ldapsearch** command to **flask_ldap3_login** settings.

To check connection to LDAP from Linux server I use this **command**:

```
ldapsearch -x -b "ou=intranet,dc=mydreamcorporation,dc=com" -H ldap://ids.mydream-corporation.com -D "myguid=myusername,ou=people,ou=intranet,dc=dreamcorporation,dc=com" -W "uid=myusername" cn uid
```

**Response from LDAP**:

> extended LDIF 
> LDAPv3 
> base <ou=intranet,dc=mydreamcorporation,dc=com> with scope subtree 
> filter: uid=myusername 
> requesting: cn uid 
> MYUSERNAME, people, intranet, mydreamcorporation.com 
> dn: myguid=myusername,ou=people,ou=intranet,dc=mydreamcorporation,dc=com 
> cn: my_name 
> uid: MYUSERNAME 
> search result 
> search: 2 
> result: 0 Success 
> numResponses: 2 
> numEntries: 1

**My flask_ldap3_login settings**:

```
from flask import Flask, url_for
from flask_ldap3_login import LDAP3LoginManager
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_user, UserMixin, current_user
from flask import render_template_string, redirect
from flask_ldap3_login.forms import LDAPLoginForm

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

my_login = "myusername"
my_password = "password"

# Hostname of your LDAP Server
app.config['LDAP_HOST'] = 'ldap://ids.mydream-corporation.com'

# Port number of your LDAP server
app.config['LDAP_PORT'] = 389

# Base DN of your directory
app.config['LDAP_BASE_DN'] = "dc=mydreamcorporation,dc=com"

# Users DN to be prepended to the Base DN
app.config['LDAP_USER_DN'] = "ou=intranet"

# Groups DN to be prepended to the Base DN
app.config['LDAP_GROUP_DN'] = 'ou=people'

# The RDN attribute for your user schema on LDAP 
app.config['LDAP_USER_RDN_ATTR'] = 'dn' 

# The Attribute you want users to authenticate to LDAP with. 
app.config['LDAP_USER_LOGIN_ATTR'] = 'myguid' 

# The Username to bind to LDAP with 
app.config['LDAP_BIND_USER_DN'] = "myguid=myusername,ou=people,ou=intranet,dc=mydreamcorporation,dc=com"

# The Password to bind to LDAP with 
app.config['LDAP_BIND_USER_PASSWORD'] = my_password 

login_manager = LoginManager(app)              # Setup a Flask-Login Manager
ldap_manager = LDAP3LoginManager(app)          # Setup a LDAP3 Login Manager

@app.route('/', methods=['POST','GET'])
def manual_login(my_login=my_login, my_password=my_password):
    result = app.ldap3_login_manager.authenticate(my_login, my_password)
    return str(result.status)
```

Unfortunately I have as a **script result**:

> AuthenticationResponseStatus.fail

I think the problem is in wrong configuration, but I cannot find where :(

I tried to add:

```
app.config['LDAP_USER_SEARCH_SCOPE'] = 'SUBTREE'
app.config['LDAP_ALWAYS_SEARCH_BIND'] = 1
```

but it didn't help and I have a message:

> invalid class in objectClass attribute: group

After Gabriel Luci comment I have change my settings to:

```
app.config['LDAP_BASE_DN'] = "ou=intranet"
app.config['LDAP_USER_DN'] = "myguid=myusername,ou=people,ou=intranet,dc=mydreamcorporation,dc=com"
#app.config['LDAP_GROUP_DN'] = 'ou=people'
app.config['LDAP_USER_RDN_ATTR'] = 'cn' 
app.config['LDAP_USER_LOGIN_ATTR'] = 'uid' 
app.config['LDAP_BIND_USER_DN'] = "myguid=myusername"
```

And now I have the same

> AuthenticationResponseStatus.fail

And in console:

> LDAPInvalidCredentialsResult - 49 - invalidCredentials - None - None - bindResponse - None

Comment: Information about versions: 

flask-ldap3-login 0.9.17 
Python 3.8.10 
Flask 1.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an answer to the question. Problem was solved by adding:
**app.config['LDAP_SEARCH_FOR_GROUPS'] = False**

Final config:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

my_login = "myusername"
my_password = "password"

app.config['LDAP_HOST'] = 'ldaps://ids.mydream-corporation.com'
app.config['LDAP_PORT'] = 636
app.config['LDAP_BASE_DN'] = "dc=mydreamcorporation,dc=com"
app.config['LDAP_USER_DN'] = "ou=people,ou=intranet"
app.config['LDAP_USER_LOGIN_ATTR'] = 'myguid'
app.config['LDAP_BIND_USER_DN'] = "myguid=myusername,ou=people,ou=intranet,dc=mydreamcorporation,dc=com"
app.config['LDAP_BIND_USER_PASSWORD'] = my_password
app.config['LDAP_USER_SEARCH_SCOPE'] = 'SUBTREE'
app.config['LDAP_SEARCH_FOR_GROUPS'] = False

login_manager = LoginManager(app)              # Setup a Flask-Login Manager
ldap_manager = LDAP3LoginManager(app)          # Setup a LDAP3 Login Manager

@app.route('/', methods=['POST','GET'])
def manual_login(my_login=my_login, my_password=my_password):
    result = app.ldap3_login_manager.authenticate(my_login, my_password)
    return str(result.status)
```

Finally I have as a **script result**:

> AuthenticationResponseStatus.success

Answer (score 0):

You tagged `active-directory`, but I suspect you may not be using AD because you're using `uid`, which isn't used in AD.

The `LDAP_HOST` and `LDAP_PORT` look right.

You have set your `LDAP_BASE_DN` to the root of your domain, but in your `ldapsearch` command, you set it to your `intranet` OU. Why the difference?

The way you set `LDAP_USER_DN` tells it that all of your user objects are in `ou=intranet,dc=mydreamcorporation,dc=com`. Is that what you intended?

The way you set `LDAP_GROUP_DN` tells it that all of the group objects are in `ou=people,dc=mydreamcorporation,dc=com`. This looks suspicious. I don't think this is what you intended.

You have set `LDAP_USER_RDN_ATTR` to `dn`, but if you're using Active Directory, that should be `cn` [according to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/b645c125-a7da-4097-84a1-2fa7cea07714#gt_8b8cbf4d-c7f7-47f9-bd6e-b402fae62c38).

You've set `LDAP_USER_LOGIN_ATTR` to `myguid`, but this looks suspicious. This should be the attribute that represents the username the user will use to login. In AD, that would be `sAMAccountName` or `userPrincipalName`. If you are using some other LDAP server, it will likely be `uid`.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I'm not sure I got the point, but I have changed my settings